# Flask-Login documentation: LoginForm()

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Following [the Flask Login manual](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I am looking for the right library to include so that I can call the LoginForm() function.

Which library do I need to include that contains the LoginForm() part?

Comment: Please indent in your code correctly and you have not mentioned what is the error you are getting.!

Comment: Fixed indentation. NameError: name 'LoginForm' is not defined. This function "LoginForm()" is indeed coming out of the blue, I strongly presume some library would need to be imported/installed up front.

Comment: Near the top of the [docs page](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the `Installation` section. It tells you to `pip install flask-login`. After that, they don't really tell you what to import, but a much further down the page you will find the package is called `flask_login`. For the code you have, you should `from flask_login import LoginForm`

Comment: @Nelson Sorry after hit I saw your comment... you are right!

Comment: @RajaSimon lol it's all good

Comment: @Happysmithers I suggest you understand how a flask app works before trying to construct something like a login form. [This](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is the official Flask website with a bare-bones example; and [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) is the "quickstart" guide which is actually pretty comprehensive

Comment: Flask app itself working well and foundations understood so far. Just now seek to protect access to certain views and discover that no simplistic sample code comprising everything can be easily found on google, at least I failed so far. Thx.

Comment: LoginForm isn't under flask_login

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`LoginForm` is a class inherit from FlaskForm 
First, you need install some modules: `pip install flask flask-login flask-wtf` 
There is a module (such as `form.py`) with content:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username')
    password = PasswordField('Password')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

This module contains form which be generated by `flask_wtf` module. And import LoginForm in your script.

```
from form import LoginForm
```

File `login.html` (in templates directory in current directory) will using flask-wtf to generate html code for LoginForm by using `wtf.quick_form(form)` 
You can read example in [this article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) to understand more detail or flask home page to understand structure of flask app